# Calculate the control points for a cubic bezier

Tags: java, bezier

I am writing an application for displaying music on an Android Tablet.

I have hit the moment when I need to draw ties and slurs - the curved lines which link two notes together.

For this I want to use a cubic bezier - but do not know how to determine the position of the two control points.

I obviously know the start (A) and end (B) points (2D), as well as the distance from the line A - B that I want the curve to go.  I put it like this because the curve is not necessarily on a horizontal plane.

Can anyone help me determine the control points needed so that the resulting curve will go through one given point - ie distance from plane and offset along the A-B plane ?

Please note, I am not a maths expert and would appreciate programming type formulas as opposed to maths formulas ... please.

Here is a concrete example :

[image: slur example]

I know the start and end points for each of these lines, as well as the point I want the curve to go through.

However, after having searched with google for the last two days, I have been unable to find the correct formula to determine the two control point positions necessary to reproduce these curves.

Comment: just place them above the start and end point at a height that looks good to you. You don't need math to figure out a good looking curve, just experiment, it's how you learn.

Comment: Your comment takes as a premise that the line will always be an upper arc and that I can use the same values all the time.  This is not the case.  The arc can be upper or lower with the A-B plane being horizontal or more or less diagonal.  I am looking for accuracy and not rough estimates.

Comment: On the surface, but "height" can be a negative value, depending on whether you know it needs to go above or below. The real question is how many different curve classes you need. Your example shows two curves that seem very different, so we might need to at the least do some "what features do they share" analysis, even if we leave out the math. Let me write up an actual answer, although if you want accuracy, good looking ties and slurs, we're going to *have* to do some math.

Comment: Thank you Mike, I agree that Maths are unavoidable - however, whilst I know this, I have very limited abilities of translating maths formulae into programming language style calculations, hence my request.

Comment: I tried to keep the actual math out of the answer. This should be good enough if you want to "just implement" it.

Comment: I would be curious as to what formula you used to find all of the modes (scales) or if you just hard coded them into an ENUM data type

Answer (score 12):

There is, unfortunately, no way to do this without relying on maths, since from your image the kind of curve we need to draw depends on what it's attached to. Analysing your given image shows the two curves don't share "construction" properties:

[image]

The red lines are the start/end baselines, and their maximum translation to fit the curve, the blue lines are the direction from start to first control, and second control to end points, the green line roughly indicates the curve's mathematical midpoint (t = 0.5) and the black line shows the maximum vertical extend of the curves.

In order to form these curves, we're going to release Linear Algebra on a standard curve and see where that gets us.

The curve on the right is actually relatively easy to construct, as it's a pretty much symmetrical curve, which we can make by scaling the standard semicircular bezier curve:

```
{ (0,0), (0,0.552), (1,0.552), (1,0) }
```

This will have the curve going straight "out", so let's distort it so that the curve starts and ends at slight angles:

```
{ (0,0), (0.2,0.552), (0.8,0.552), (1,0) }
```

That's on a straight unit line, and with the height of a semicircle, and going up, so we need to scale it down to around a quarter height, and possibly stick some minus signs in front of the y coordinates.

```
{ (0,0), (0.2, +/- 0.138), (0.8, +/- 0.138), (1,0) }
```

and scale it to match the line length you need it to be based on the start point p1 and end point p4,

```
D = distance(p1, p4)
{ (0,0), (0.2 * D, 0.138 * D), (0.8 * D, 0.138 * D), (D,0) }
```

then we rotate the coordinates so that they're on the correct angled line, using the angle between your line and the horizontal, and sticking that angle in a rotation matrix:

```
phi = atan2(p4.y - p1.y, p4.x - p1.x)

{
  (0, 0),
  (0.2 * D * cos(phi) - 0.138 * D * sin(phi), 0.2 * D * sin(phi) + 0.138 * D * cos(phi)),
  (D * cos(phi) - 0.138 * D * sin(phi), D * sin(phi) + 0.138 * D * sin(phi)),
  (D * cos(phi), D * sin(phi)
}
```

This looks "mathy" but it's not. cos(phi) and sin(phi), if you already have phi, are just two numbers, there's no maths involved here, just dumb arithmatics.

The final step is then to translate all the coordinates so that they're in the right spot on your page:

```
{
  (p1.x + 0, p1.y + 0),
  (p1.x + 0.2 * D * cos(phi) - 0.138 * D * sin(phi), p1.y + 0.2 * D * sin(phi) + 0.138 * D * cos(phi)),
  (p1.x + D * cos(phi) - 0.138 * D * sin(phi), p1.y + D * sin(phi) + 0.138 * D * sin(phi)),
  (p1.x + D * cos(phi), p1.y + D * sin(phi)
}
```

Done. Your second curve is easy to make.

The curve on the left is slightly more work, but only slightly. We -perhaps unintuitively- start in the same way, forming exactly the same type of curve as before, stopping before the rotation. We can observe that if we lay the curve from your image flat on the horizontal, it's actually a regular scaled semicircle, but sheared the right. So let's just do that:

before rotation:

```
{ (0,0), (0.2 * D, 0.138 * D), (0.8 * D, 0.138 * D), (D,0) }
```

shearing horizontally

```
float sx = <strength of the shear>
{ (0,0), (0.2 * D + 0.138 * D * sx, 0.138 * D), (0.8 * D + 0.138 * D * sx, 0.138 * D), (D,0) }
```

rotating:

```
phi = atan2(p4.y - p1.y, p4.x - p1.x)

{
  (0, 0),
  ((0.2 * D + 0.138 * D * sx) * cos(phi) - 0.138 * D * sin(phi), (0.2 * D + 0.138 * D * sx) * sin(phi) + 0.138 * D * cos(phi)),
  ((D + 0.138 * D * sx) * cos(phi) - 0.138 * D * sin(phi), (D + 0.138 * D * sx) * sin(phi) + 0.138 * D * cos(phi)),
  (D * cos(phi), D * sin(phi)
}
```

And then the last translation step is the same. Again just mostly plugging in numbers, although this time you're going to have to play around with the shearing value to see which looks best.

**Free parameters**

We can control how "bowy" the curves are by changing how much we scale the initial semicircle. A 0.25 factor is relatively tight, 0.33 is relatively bubbly. We can also control how sharp the shear is for curves like you left tie. A shear of 1 is subtle, a shear of 1.75 is acutely abrupt.

**Why does this work**

Bezier curves, despite having the word curve in their name, are linear interpolations of linear interpolations of ... of lines. Applying linear transformations to the coordinates that build up the curve preserves the properties of the curve, so instead of trying to work with the full curve, we can just mess with the four coordinates and trust the curve will look right.

So we're taking the four coordinates of a curve we know the coordinates for, and then apply all the transformations we need to get the curve we want:

```
(x,y) . scale . (shearx?) . rotation, + (tx,ty)
```

which is:

```
|x| . | D 0 | . | 1 shearx | . |cos(phi) -sin(phi)| + |tx|
|y|   | 0 D |   | 0    1   |   |sin(phi)  cos(phi)|   |ty|
```

And matrix operations can be collapsed into a single matrix (which is why computers are so good at 2D/3D stuff - it's all just matrices, so very complex operations are still just a single matrix applied to a million coordinates).

In fact, we can even work in the translation as a matrix operation if we treat the coordinates as 3d coordinates, with the z value always being 1. But that's no longer really relevant to your question.

**A jsiddle**

A fiddle for a step by step implementation of your left tie can be found at http://jsfiddle.net/CLbUF/1, but this does not have all the operations collapsed into a single operation. You'll need to do that yourself.